# Ana's damage vs Lucio's healing?

Tags: overwatch

Straight question: how does Lucio's heal-over-time output compare to Ana's damage-over-time output?

Is firing into a crowd useless when there's a Lucio there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ana does 80 dmg per shot, being able to shoot 1.1 shots a second. Ana has a potential of dealing 88 damage per second (assuming with infinite amount of shots). Lucio without "Amp it Up" does 12.5 healing per second. Amp it up healing does 40 per second.

Lets just use Lucio as an example. He has 200 health.

Killing Lucio would take 3 shots without amp it up. With Amp it Up, it would take about 4-5 shots since Amp it up would lasts 3 seconds long.

However your Biotic grenades allow you deny any heal your enemy can get from Lucio. So I'd say no, it's not useless.

Edit: There's a recent patch that came out for PC version for Ana that allows her to fire 20% faster and her clip can now hold 10 bullets instead of 8. So firing into a group of people with Lucio just got better

Source: http://www.polygon.com/2016/7/26/12291162/overwatch-patch-ana-buff-mccree-nerf-pc

Comment: Great point about using Biotic Grenade to negate Lucio's AoE heal.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth forgot to mention that Ana has 8 bullets in a magazine. So with your biotic grenade, you can land a couple kills even with a Lucio with one clip. That's if your aim is on point.

Comment: Charging your ultimate is never useless.

Answer (score 0):

Ana can be at times, if you use her you can do a lot of healing at once, and quick, but if you are Lucio you can only do 40 with amp it up a second. Where as Ana can do 100 within 2 seconds if they are far away and you chunk a grenade.  Her rifle does 75 healing and per second where Lucio can only do 40 a second.